# Why there are two different answer in same compare template function

Tags: c++11

When I try to implement a template to compare two variables' value.

When I try passing string as parameters then the program couldn't compare the value right.

However when I add two same variables this code get me a right result.
Just as the picture shows.

[image]

Comment: The first link is the picture I want to show.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please post the code here instead of a link to the image of the code.

Comment: Also specify what does it mean that `The program couldn't compare the value right`: input, program output, expected output (and why it's expected).

Comment: Answer: `Max(x, y)` compares strings, while `Max("1", "5")` compares pointers.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <typename K>
K Max(K x, K y){
  return (x>y)?x:y;
}

int main()
{
  string x = "1";
  string y = "5";

  cout<<"Max(string) "<<Max("1","5")<<endl;
}

sorry, here is the code.
When I declared the parameters in main, the code run corrent.
else, the code run incorrect. And thank to you guys answer, it should caused by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You passed it a `const char *`  pointer to compare and that will compare the pointer addresses, not the contents with '>'. As these are from different objects/strings, you have no way to know which will be first or last in memory, and it may vary from compile to compile, or even potentially run to run.

As you had the `std::string` local variable, I assume you intended to pass that, which does have comparison operators to compare the contents. If you want to pass a string literal as an `std::string` to such a template function, you must do it explicitly, such as:

```
Max<std::string>("a", "b"); // K is std::string, so both parameters will use the implicit constructor
Max(std::string("a"), std::string("b")); // Explicitly construct strings
```

If you do want `Max` to work with char pointers, you might overload or specialise it to use say `strcmp`, which does compare the contents.

```
template<class T> T Max(T x, T y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
template<> const char* Max(const char *x, const char *y)
{
    return strcmp(x, y) > 0 ? x : y;
}
template<> char* Max(char *x, char *y)
{
    return strcmp(x, y) > 0 ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I understand that.